# How to display two table in one path using EJS and Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ejs

I'm doing a simple project. I was searching for the solution online but I can't find anything that is exact to what I am doing right now. I have a collection table in my MongoDB. I want to display two displays that filters the role. One table for Admin, and then one table for User.

[Please see the image of the example table collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzeBk.png)

Here's my code from app.js

```
app.get("/", function (req, res) {

  User.find({accountrole: "user"}, function(err, users) {
    res.render('portal',{users:users});


 // User.find({accountrole: "admin"}, function(err, admin) {
  //      res.render('portal',{admin:admin});
});
```

This works only in one table since I put the accountrole: "user" inside the bracket.Please check the comment inside the code,I wanna put it too so I can have two tables but filters the admin and user.

and then here's my code from my portal. ejs

```
<table class="table table-hover citizen-table">
            <thead class="table-dark">
              <tr>
                <!-- <th scope="col">#</th> -->
                <th scope="col">Accout Role</th>
                <th scope="col">First Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Last Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Email</th>
             
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <% users.forEach(function(users){ %>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row"><%= users.accountrole %></th>
                <td><%= users.firstname %></td>
                <td><%= users.lastname %></td>
                <td><%= users.email %></td>
       
              </tr>
              <% }); %>
            </tbody>
          </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very easy to achieve by using the `async/await` syntax. Fetch the users, fetch the admins, pass both objects together to your template.

```
app.get("/", async function (req, res) {

    const users = await User.find({accountrole: "user"})
                        .lean() // Return simple JSON data, not a Mongoose objects collection (simpler and faster)
                        .exec(); // Returns a true Promise, not just a thenable. You can then await the Promise

    const admins = await User.find({accountrole: "admin"}).lean().exec();
    
    res.render('portal',{users, admins}); // or {users:users, admins:admins}, same thing
})
```